# Laravel @section not showing

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

My issue is that when I define a section in a laravel blade (not master) I cannot display it's content on the page, however if I yield it on the master.blade.php it works fine. So how can I make this page display:

> section 'content'
>   section 'template'

```
    @extends('layouts.master')

@section('title', 'Website Builder')
@section('content')
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{!! asset('js/template.js') !!}"></script>
@endsection
        @section('template') 
        <div class= "container template_class ">
            @foreach ($templates as $template)
        <a class="content-link" href="{{ asset($template->file )}}">
        <img id = "image" src="{{ asset($template->image )}}"/>
        </a>
            @endforeach
        </div>
 <div id="content-link2"></div>
            <div class="container">
            @yield('content')
            @yield('template')
        </div>
@endsection
@show
```

Comment: Isn't documentation clear enough?

Comment: I wouldn't ask if it would be clear

Comment: Mate please re-read documentation what you are asking is right there... by "read" I mean READ not just skim. `In this example, the sidebar section is utilizing the @parent directive to append (rather than overwriting) content to the layout's sidebar. The @parent directive will be replaced by the content of the layout when the view is rendered.`

Answer (score 3):

So, if you already have a `@section` defined in the master layout, it will be overriden unless you specify `@parent` inside the child layout's `@section`.

But for `@yield`, it always gets the section from the child layout. That means it always overrides the `@yield` part, even if it has a default defined as `@yield('section', 'Default Content')`

Hope this works!

Comment: okay so why is my @section('template') not displaying keeping in mind that it is a child layout

Comment: @PrzemekWojtas you have your `@yield('template')` inside you `@section('template')` and `@endsection`. You need to place your `@yield('template')` outside your `@section('template') @endsection`.

Comment: That makes sense however why does @yield('template') is being applied to all pages across the website, while I have only used it in this child layout?

Comment: @RobinDirksen, Laravel doct at https://tutorials.kode-blog.com/laravel-blade-template omits `@parent` and says the master layout's text will be shown in output . Just go to the 'Extending the master layout' section and you'll find it. Any explanation ?